# Changing fill/stroke of svg path elements in d3.js tick event shows no effect

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to learn more d3.js and working with this example http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347. In particular, I am trying to change the color of the edges connecting nodes by adding code to the `tick` event. I have modified `tick()` to be the following:

```
// update force layout (called automatically each iteration)
function tick() {
  // draw directed edges with proper padding from node centers
  path.attr('d', function(d) {
    var deltaX = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        deltaY = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY),
        normX = deltaX / dist,
        normY = deltaY / dist,
        sourcePadding = d.left ? 17 : 12,
        targetPadding = d.right ? 17 : 12,
        sourceX = d.source.x + (sourcePadding * normX),
        sourceY = d.source.y + (sourcePadding * normY),
        targetX = d.target.x - (targetPadding * normX),
        targetY = d.target.y - (targetPadding * normY);
    return 'M' + sourceX + ',' + sourceY + 'L' + targetX + ',' + targetY;
  });

  /**** this is the beginning of my modification ****/
    path.attr('fill', function(d){
        return d.left ? 'red':'blue'
});

    path.attr('stroke', function(d){
        return d.left ? 'red':'blue'
});    
  /**** this is the end of my modification ****/   

  circle.attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  });
}
```

However, all the edges continue to be black. I have done a ctrl-f through the code and neither of these properties is otherwise set for `paths` so I am wondering why I see no effect. It would appear that `svg:paths` do in fact have `stroke` and `fill` properties ([see this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)).

Also if I put a `console.log(d.target.id);` command in either of my two added attribute assignment functions, the console output is sensible. Finally, if I replace 'red' and 'blue' with `d3.rgb(colors(5))` or similar values, this also does not have an effect, so I don't think the problem is the color value.

Why doesn't my code affect the svg elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths (after your function has been applied) look like this.

```
<path class="link" fill="blue" stroke="blue" ... />
```

The link class does this to paths of class link.

```
path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  cursor: default;
}
```

And the class CSS has higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the fill and stroke attributes so that's what gets used.

You could remove the fill and stroke lines from the path.link CSS if you want the fill and stroke attribute colours to apply.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing out what I should have already checked! (argh) Much obliged.